# Using map to return a new array with a sentence for each object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `map` to return a new array containing sentences for each object.

I've tried a few things but can not seem to get the logic right for returning the values of each object.

An object as such:

```
const person = [
  {
    name: "James",
    nationality: "English",
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: "Pierre",
    nationality: "French",
    age: "23"
  }
]
```

Should return:

```
[
  "My name is James, I am English and I am 26",
  "My name is Pierre, I am French and I am 23"
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the result you want to return? It only has one sentence, not a sentence for each object.

Comment: Please show what you tried, so we can help you understand where you went wrong, instead of doing your homework for you from scratch.

Comment: Barmar, is correct. This implies it will build a string array every 2 objects??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop thru the array. Use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct the desired string.

```js
const person = [{
    name: "James",
    nationality: "English",
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: "Pierre",
    nationality: "French",
    age: "23"
  }
];

const result = person.map(o => `My name is ${o.name}, I am ${o.nationality} and I am ${o.age}`);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was putting " " instead of back ticks! Silly

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = person.map(x => {
  return `My name is ${x.name}, I am ${x.nationality} and I am ${x.age}`;
})
```

If you'd like them combined, use

```
arr.join(', ');
```